# How to detect when a frame url is changed?

Tags: javascript, html, frames

I have the following:

```
<frame src="myframe.htm" id="myframe"/>
<frame src="http://www.google.com" id="external" />
```

How to detect any new url in the frame `"external"` when clicking a link on it so i can display it on the frame `"myframe"` ?
I want to use javascript for that

Thanks

Comment: It *might* work to set up a handler for the "load" event of the frame, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: Also it's good that you want to use Javascript, because you have basically no other choice :-)

Answer (score 1):

> How to detect any new url in the frame

If the iframe's document is not on the same domain as the parent page, the short answer is: You can't due to the [Single Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript).

However, if you control the page containing the links, you *might* be able to give links a target like `<a target="external" href=.....` which *should* open the links in the other iframe.